# getting wrong info in date time function

Tags: php, date

I think this should work for me setting

```
$var = date('H:i');
echo $var;
```

and using the `date()` function I will get the date and time for India. But I have changed the  settings in `php.ini` file to `date.timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata'` but I'm still getting the wrong time.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: will you show the full code

Comment: what version of `PHP` are you using?

Comment: No warnings? And what's wrong time? Code, expected and actual output would help.

Answer (score 1):

have you used

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
?>
```

?

Comment: it worked but i can swear date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');  was not working 15 minutes

Comment: did you restart the server after changing `php.ini`?

Comment: @AbhishekTripathi was there any spelling mistakes before?

Answer (score 1):

use

> [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) — Sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script

```
$timezone = "Asia/Calcutta";
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')){
   date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

   echo date('H:i')
}
```